# Are all 10 inch android tablets identified as xlarge?

Tags: android, screen

I'm trying to provide a landscape view  for 10inch (or larger) tablets and for all other devices (7 inch tablets, phones, samsung galaxy note etc.. ) a portrait view.

I'm wondering if I can rely on android identifying the devices as xlarge , and then assume it is at least a 10 inch tablet. Which would mean android won't identify any tablets less than 10 inch as xlarge (this is what I'm hoping for , but may not be true).

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe they are now, but I wouldn't count on it staying that way for long, as they seem to come out with something new every few weeks. If I were you, I would just make the images that are displayed on startup  squares, then make a small image with a background color or texture. You can then draw that small image onto the background (or tile it) and put the square image above it (if that makes sense). That is the new way to make a cool startup screen, anyhow. As for the interface, just make anchor objects of some kind and setup the actual interface in code.

Comment: Regarding the anchor objects, did you mean don't use the xml layouts (except as a starting point) and build all views programmatically based on the screen size?

Comment: For the most part, yes. I do realize that there are some exceptions, but it is generally easier to build for multiple screen sizes if the code can "think" about the size it has to work with and build what is best for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) the xlarge size is at least 960dp x 720dp, where 1px = ~ 1dp at a resolution of 160dpi.  So these screens must be (roughly) 6" x 4.5" or larger, which gives a minimum diagonal of 7.5".  So you can't rely on the screen being at least 10".

In any case, if you refer to the section on [Declaring Tablet Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts), it explains why using xlarge et al is no longer desirable.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly what Google recommends.

However:

- Device manufacturers can tinker with this stuff, so it is not out of the question for, say, an 8.9-inch tablet to get categorized as `-xlarge` if the manufacturer chooses to do so, though this seems far less common nowadays (perhaps due to better Googly enforcement)
- Non-tablets can be `-xlarge`, such as Google TV on a 1080p display
- You may be better served [using `-swNNNdp` rather than the older buckets](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

All that being said, I am confused by your stated objective:

> I'm trying to provide a landscape view for 10inch (or larger) tablets and for all other devices (7 inch tablets, phones, samsung galaxy note etc.. ) a portrait view.

You should be providing both portrait and landscape layouts for all supported device sizes. Users should be welcome to hold their device however they wish, without artificial restrictions. Just because *you* might prefer to use those tablets that way does not mean that all of your users will.

Comment: I have an existing application in the market which only supports portrait mode for all devices. On smaller tablets and phones I can't support landscape mode because that doesn't give me enough real estate to display what I need to display.  Now I'm trying to support landscape mode on larger tablets where I can also display some additional information which will not be available in the portrait mode. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @saj-and: "I have an existing application in the market which only supports portrait mode for all devices" -- this is not a good thing. "because that doesn't give me enough real estate to display what I need to display" -- AFAIK, there are precisely zero devices in existence that when you rotate them causes the screen size to shrink. Hence, you have the same "real estate" in either case. "Hope this makes sense" -- not in the slightest.